# Realm : How to delete object from RLMArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have created simple relational database (like exists in other dbs) model in the iOS Realm DB. Where i  created 2 separate Realm models (tables) user ids with other details and a Wishlist, where the user has an array of Wishlist using `RLMArray`. Wishlist can contain 1 or more products as in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42106351/relational-database-in-realm). In this model table with user ids is constant but Wishlist table of `RLMArray` can be updated or deleted. I am able to update `RLMArray` using realm `addOrUpdateObject` **but How can i delete elements from `RLMArray`?**
Example relational database model is below :

[image]

Code is similar to this :

```
#import <Realm/Realm.h>

@class User;

// User model
@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *user_id;
@property RLMArray< Wishlist *>< Wishlist > *wishlist;
@end

// Wishlist model
@interface Wishlist : RLMObject
@property NSString *id;
@property NSInteger *activity;
@property NSInteger *cost;

@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Wishlist) // define RLMArray<Person>

// Implementations
@implementation User
@end // none needed

@implementation Wishlist
@end // none needed
```

Read data from realm :

```
RLMResults *watchlistDB = [Watchlist allObjects];
WatchlistDB = [realm_data objectAtIndex:index];
RLMArray *realm_array = WatchlistDB.watchlist;
```

Insert New activity:

```
User *user_realm = [[MyWatchlistDB alloc] init];
user_realm.user_id = _user_id;
user_realm.name = _user_name;
for (NSDictionary *tempDict in activity)
{
    Wishlist *wishlist_realm = [[Wishlist alloc] init];
    newWatchlist.id =[tempDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    newWatchlist.activity =[tempDict objectForKey:@"activity"];
    newWatchlist.cost = [tempDict objectForKey:@"cost"];

    [user_realm.wishlist addObject:newWatchlist];
}
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addOrUpdateObject:user_realm];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

**How can i delete elements from RLMArray ? to update user wishlist when he delete some activities ?**

Comment: delete is also update, just put the remove code between `beginWriteTransaction ` and `commitWriteTransaction `

Comment: Yes. I but in update i need to read RLMArray then remove from index and `commitWriteTransaction`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some how i manage to delete data from realm. Using `RLMArray` and `addOrUpdateObject`.

```
RLMArray<Wishlist> *wishlist_array = Userdb_realm.wishlist; // reading existing data
User *Userdb = [[User alloc] init];
Userdb.user_id = _Userdb_id;
Userdb.name = _Userdb_name;

for (NSString *temp in delArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<[wishlist_array count]; i++) {
        Wishlist *wishlistTodel = wishlist_array[i];
        if ([wishlistTodel.user_id isEqualToString:temp]) {
            RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
            [realm beginWriteTransaction];
            [wishlist_array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            [realm commitWriteTransaction];
            break;
        }

    }


}
Userdb.wishlist = wishlist_array;
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm];
[realm beginWriteTransaction];
[realm addOrUpdateObject:Userdb];
[realm commitWriteTransaction];
```

**If anyone have better solution can answer here.**
Thank you for all your response.

Answer (score 3):

Realm is an object database, not a relational database, so you shouldn't need to implement a foreign key system in order to link objects. If you want to see which `User` a `WishList` item belongs, you can use the `RLMLinkingObject` feature to provide a reverse-lookup instead of what you're doing now.

```
// Wishlist model
@interface Wishlist : RLMObject
@property NSInteger *activity;
@property NSInteger *cost;
@property (readonly) RLMLinkingObjects *users;
@end
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(Wishlist) // define RLMArray<Person>

// Implementations
@implementation Wishlist
+ (NSDictionary *)linkingObjectsProperties {
    return @{
        @"users": [RLMPropertyDescriptor descriptorWithClass:User.class 
                                                propertyName:@"wishlist"]
    };
}
@end
```

This means you can call `wishlist.users.firstObject` to get the user in which that `Wishlist` belongs, without needing to do a lot of manual linking work.

Additionally, if you've got a Realm property in `User` that you want to use to uniquely identify objects, you can explicitly mark that one as a primary key which lets you query for specific objects (Even though we call it a primary key for convinience, it's still not the same as a relational database).

```
// User model
@interface User : RLMObject
@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *user_id;
@property RLMArray< Wishlist *>< Wishlist > *wishlist;
@end

@implementation User
    + (NSString *)primaryKey {
        return @"user_id";
    }
@end
```

`User` and `Wishlist` objects are stored in separate tables in Realm, with neither explicitly owning each other (They're just making references). If a `Wishlist` item is unique to just one `User`, then you can just delete the `Wishlist` object from Realm and it will get removed from the `RLMArray` as well.

To delete all of the wishlist entries belonging to a single user, you could simply do this.

```
//Get John Smith's entry
User *johnSmith = [User objectForPrimaryKey:@"084"];

//Delete all of the items in John's wishlist
RLMRealm *realm = [RLMRealm defaultRealm]

[realm transactionWithBlock:^{
    [realm deleteObjects:johnSmith.wishlist];
}];
```

Comment: I will try this. Thanks

Comment: How can i delete single object inside wishlist not all objects.

Comment: You can use `[RLMRealm deleteObject:]` to delete a single object. If you use `[RLMArray removeObjectAtIndex:]`, that will remove the object from `wishlist`, but won't delete it from Realm.

Answer (score 0):

From [Realm CocoaDocs](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/Realm/2.4.1/Classes/RLMArray.html#//api/name/removeObjectAtIndex:)

```
- (void)removeObjectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
```

Comment: I tried this already for this i have to store `RLMArray` then delete from index again attach  `RLMArray` to the model. is there any other way.